# As a US Citizen can I open a Canadian bank account without my social security number?

Tags: canada, banking, social-security, privacy, foreign

As I stated in the title: will I need to provide my Social Security Number if I choose to open a bank in Canada as a US Citizen?

Comment: If the bank asks you for it, and asks you to check a box saying 'Not a US citizen', then you are committing a form of fraud by doing this. You may find that local credit unions (which might not trade in US products, and therefore might not need to follow all relevant US banking laws) may be less likely to ask you this. You could call around to credit unions near you to find out.

Comment: Note even if you avoid FATCA reporting by the bank, _you_ are still required to file FBAR for (most) financial accounts totalling more than USD10k, and 8938 for (somewhat broader) assets totalling more than a higher threshold if you must file income tax returns -- which you must if you have more than minimal income, although if you reside and work in Canada (which you didn't say) this return will often result in no or little _tax_. And there can be harsh penalties for failing to make the required reports on accounts, even if you owe no tax.